# Document/view architecture

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

I want to implement an application based on the Netbeans Platform which handles data (gathered in a document) and displays them in different ways (in views).

So far, I have created a module with a file type (named Document) and a window. In the window, I have put a JPanel and customized the code to replace the standard JPanel class with the "DocumentVisualElement" class. But instantiating a "DocumentVisualElement" needs a Lookup instance. I have tried to get one with "Lookup.getDefault()" but this triggers an error in the "DocumentVisualElement" constructor : the "DocumentDataObject" can't be found in the Lookup.

Have I missed something? Is there a better way to do what I want to do?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

A JTextArea can be created with a backing Document.

The Java Swing components hierarchy would be as follows:

```
JPanel
    JScrollPane
        JTextArea
```

Comment: In fact, I already have a JPanel in which I could display what the document contains. My problem is that I don't know how to declare and access the backing document. For me, but I may be wrong, adding a module of "File type" to the application doesn't add an instance of the document.

Comment: @Zelig63: I guess I wasn't clear.  You do not display a Document in a JPanel.  You display a Document in a JTextArea or a JEditorArea.

Comment: When I created my "file type" module, I have got three new classes created for me : "DocumentDataObject", "DocumentTemplate" and DocumentVisualElement". Do you mean I have to create a "DocumentDataObject" instance in a new class implementing a "JTextArea" or "JEditorArea"? And what do I do with my "DocumentVisualElement" class?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is [MultiView Windows](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-core-multiview/overview-summary.html) - The same functionality is used for displaying different views of GUI forms in NetBeans (Code and Form views).

The [File Type Integration Tutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-filetype.html) may be a perfect fit, if not then just read the section on [adding multiple MultiView segments](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-filetype.html#multiview)

Comment: You are right. MultiView seems to be the solution to my problem. What I miss now is how to create an instance of my "DocumentDataObject" and to have the data it contains accessible to the "DocumentVisualElement" for display.